# RSync Include Exclude Rules

Tags: unix, rsync

I need to implement a selective rsync to a given folder that is strucutred like this:

```
random.pdf
backup.gz
htdocs
   - api.html
   - report.xml
   - otherfile.html
folder
   - private.html
```

I need to create a rule to exclude all pdfs, all xmls, and every folder instead of **htdocs**. Would like to include all .gz as well.
So i came up with the following rule:

```
rsync -azP --delete --exclude="*.pdf" --exclude="*.xml" --include="*.gz" --include="htdocs/*" --exclude="*" (...)
```

Somehow this particular rules only get me access to the *.gz and I sincerely can't figure out why the htdocs folder won't pass as well. Can anyone give me a hint ? Thanks

Comment: see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19296415/373151

Comment: you might also want to look into the --exclude-from and --include-from flags [--exclude-from=FILE read exclude patterns from FILE --include-from=FILE read include patterns from FILE]

Comment: if I use the --exclude="*" at the end, I can't pass the htdocs folder :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the --dry-run option (very very helpful), figured out that my expression wasn't that good. This was wrong

```
--include="htdocs/*" --exclude="*"
```

And it was fixed by the following code

```
--include="htdocs" --exclude="/*"
```

I still don't understand very well the solution, but it works fine. Thanks for the tips