# python or any other script to find files and copy them into another folder

Tags: python, bash

I have several folders (let's say 10 folders) each of which has several subfolders.
I want to search each one of the folders in root and find the files which contain `RGB` in their filename and copy them into a folder. 
the result would be like 10 folders with files that just have `RGB` in their filenames.

Comment: How do you know which folder it goes into?  Perhaps this is better for http://superuser.com/ to answer.

Comment: It seems like you have not even tried to solve this trivial problem yourself.

Comment: What do you mean with _in root_? Do you want to recurse in the sub-directories? If yes do you want the same hierarchy of sub-directories in the copy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296190/rsync-include-from-vs-exclude-from-what-is-the-actual-difference

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @RenaudPacalet by root i mean the location of the disk that 10 original folder is located. No I don't want the sub-folder hierarchy in the copy.

Comment: What about looking at the `cp` (copy) command? Type `man cp`, read the manual from top to bottom, then do the same with `man bash`, read the section about `pathname expansion` and... do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use os.walk to iterate through the folders
2. Get file name having RGB along with the parent folder name
3. Use the join function to create the new location and copy the file to the location